# How to get 100% width of content with css?

Tags: css, width, fluid

I want to get a fluid layout and have encountered some issues with how I designed my layout.

What I have in mind is a layout where the content section of the page always fills the entire browser in width. To the left of the content I've got two menus that may vary in width.

A quick sketch of the desired layout can be found here:
[Layout](http://i39.tinypic.com/2zgc8b6.png)

Comment: what issues did you come up with??.. add some relevant code to depict your problem..

Comment: How should the height work? Is the whole thing supposed to fill the screen? What happens when there is more content than can fit?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend implementing one of Matthew James Taylor's [*Ultimate multi-column liquid layouts.*](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-multi-column-liquid-layouts-em-and-pixel-widths)

Answer (score 0):

Width is always 100% or 'max' unless you specify differently. Is there a working example that shows your hardships that you are describing?